# DVWP MaximumRows ParameterBinding not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, xslt

Is it possible to use ParamaterBinding for MaximumRows?

The following does not work.

**Following set in SelectParmaters**

```
<webpartpages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="MaximumRows" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="1" Name="MaximumRows"></webpartpages:DataFormParameter>
```

**Following bindings configured**

```
<property name="ParameterBindings" type="string">
<ParameterBinding Name="MaximumRows" DefaultValue="3"/>
</property>
```

Changing the binding as you can see has no impact at all on the webpart. It remains showing 1 as set in the default.

This paramaterbinding works fine for WebUrl and ListName but seems to not work for MaximumRows. Can others confirm?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue that you have experienced. I'm hoping you've already solved this issue, if so, could you please tell me how you did it? Sabry

Comment: Not the answer you want I'm sure, but I had to go with removing the binding for maximum rows and had to use a static parameter instead. No end user flexibility I'm afraid!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to aggregate the XSLTListViewWebPart, like this:

```
var xlcwp = new XsltListViewWebPart { ListId = myList.ID };
var ds = xlcwp.DataSource as SPDataSource;
if (ds == null) return;

var maximumRows = ds.SelectParameters["MaximumRows"];
if (maximumRows == null) return;

maximumRows.DefaultValue = "3";
```